# On Mac OS X 10.7, Java Control Panel crashes unexpectedly

Tags: macos, crash, java, system-settings

I'm wondering if this is a serious problem that I should be concerned about.

I have the latest version of Java installed (currently `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)` via command `java -version`).

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. When I try to open the Java Control Panel by opening System Preferences and selecting Java, I get a spontaneous crash with the error: "Java Control Panel quit unexpectedly."

[image: Crash]

There's an error report that shows a lot of detailed information about the crash.

Is this an issue? And how can I fix this?

Comment: According to [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html), you need OS X 10.8.3 for newer to run the latest JRE

Answer (score 2):

For your older version of OS X, you probably should have downloaded a legacy version of Java. Try this link: [Download Java for OS X 2017-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Although probably good advice, it doesn't seem to make a difference in my ability to open the Java Control Panel. After installing Java for OS X 2017-001, I still get ```Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)``` from the command ```$ java -version```.